# How to make new pointer in Swift?

Tags: swift

Say I have a var with an Int:

```
var f = 3
```

Now I would like to have an `UnsafePointer<Int>` to that var. If I were passing it to a function I could do it like this:

```
functionTakesAPointer(&f)
```

But I need to be able to do something like this:

```
var g = &f
```

which is not allowed.

NB: I am aware this is not the 'Swift way'; this is a highly contrived example I invented while fiddling around with Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mutable pointer to variable f as follows:

```
let g = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&f, { $0 })
```

And here's how you can create an immutable pointer to f.

```
let g = withUnsafePointer(&f, { $0 })
```